# C store digit and spaces in char array

Tags: c

How can i store digits and spaces in an array? I am using a char array. Here is my code:

```
char m[100];
int i;
for(i = 0; i < 5; i++)
   if(i == 2)
      m[i] = ' ';
   else
      m[i] = i;
```

How can i print the content of m? (01 34)

Comment: You are not asking the right question... You are not storing what you think you are.

Answer (score 4):

Here this should work for you

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) 
{
    char m[100];
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
       if(i == 2)
           m[i] = ' ';
       else
           m[i] = '0' + i; //<< Note ascii of 0 is 48
    }
    m[i]= '\0';
    printf("%s",m);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What's up with all the downvotes?

Comment: Guess what happens, if `i` gets bigger than 5.

Comment: @Superlokkus - the code has hardcoded values - it can never reach that value. `i` has to be less than `100`.

Comment: I upvoted, as it works for obvious cases.

Comment: Maybe because the question is crap.

Comment: Don't downvote an answer if the question is at fault. Vote to close the question.

Comment: @ABcDexter it does not work if the system does not use the ASCII table.

Comment: @mch- Got your point, made my edit.

Comment: @mch Yes, you're right. But again, the question is unclear.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that you set `m[i] = '\0'` for one-past the element you want to print (this is the null-terminator), then use a `printf` like function, with `%s` as the formatter.

For the digits, you need to use `m[i] = '0' + i`, else you'll be attempting to print *control characters* rather than the digits themselves.